# How to solve Error `Axes' object has no attribute 'is_first_col'?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('D:\pima-indians-diabetes3.csv')

X = df.iloc[:, 0:8]
y = df.iloc[:, 8]

ss = StandardScaler()
scaled_X = pd.DataFrame(ss.fit_transform(X), columns = X.columns)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (12, 4))
X.plot(kind='kde', title = 'Raw data', ax=ax[0])
scaled_X.plot(kind='kde', title = 'StandardScaler', ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

I followed exactly same with practice book but I got this error.

`Axes' object has no attribute 'is_first_col'` on this two lines

```
X.plot(kind='kde', title = 'Raw data', ax=ax[0])
scaled_X.plot(kind='kde', title = 'StandardScaler', ax=ax[1])
```

I've faced this error for the first time and don't know why this happens. Could anyone help me with it? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem of 'SubplotSpec' object has no attribute 'is_first_col', after upgrade to pandas 2.0.

It is fixed until reinstalled matplotlib.
pip install --upgrade matplotlib